# React-Native: How to render variables stored in a POST request on screen?

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I have a post route:

```
router.post("/projects", async (req, res) => {
  const {
    projectName,
    projectDescription,
    projectBudget,
    projectDuration,
    industry,
    companyName,
    numberOfEmployees,
    diamond,
  } = req.body;
  console.log(diamond);

  const [projectDiamond] = diamond;

  const { criteria } = projectDiamond;

  //diamond is an array containing an object, and that object contains another object called criteria, hence destructuring the 'criteria' object. It's redundant I know but this thing is out of scope of this question!

  if (
    !projectName ||
    !projectDescription ||
    !projectBudget ||
    !projectDuration ||
    !industry ||
    !companyName ||
    !numberOfEmployees ||
    !diamond
  ) {
    return res.status(422).send({ error: "Must provide all project details" });
  }

  try {
    const project = new Project({
      projectName,
      projectDescription,
      projectBudget,
      projectDuration,
      industry,
      companyName,
      numberOfEmployees,
      diamond,
      userId: req.user._id,
    });

    const recommendation = await Recommendation.find({
      "diamond.criteria": criteria,
    }); //Need to render this on screen

    const projectsWithSameDiamond = await Project.find({
      "diamond.criteria": criteria,
    }); //Need to render this on screen
    
    const projectsWithSameIndustry = await Project.find({ industry }); //Need to render this on screen
    
    await project.save();
   
    
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(422).send({ error: err.message });
  }
});
```

It's a post request as you can see. Now every time a user let's say "post a new project", I want to retrieve "recommendation" and "projects with similar diamond" and "projects with similar industry" (you can see that I am trying to save all three of them in different variables in the post route).

Is there a way to retrieve these three variables and use them in a component in react native?

Suppose I have a component, A.js:

```
const A = () => {
 return(
  //returning something here
 )
)
}
```

Now suppose this component uses axios to send http post request to the route I have defined:

```
const A = () => {
 ...
 axios.post("/projects", {projectName,
    projectDescription,
    projectBudget,
    projectDuration,
    industry,
    companyName,
    numberOfEmployees,
    diamond} );
 return(
  //returning something here
 )
)
}
```

After the request has finished successfully ( and a project is posted) I want to let's say render those three variables on screen

```
const A = () => {
 return(
  <Text>{recommendation}</Text> {/*Not sure how to do get this after using axios to post new project */}
  <Text>{projectWithSimilarDiamond</Text> {/*Not sure how to do get this after using axios to post new project */}
  <Text>{projectWithSimilarIndustry}</Text> {/*Not sure how to do get this after using axios to post new project */}
 
 )
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using state

snack: https://snack.expo.io/@ashwith00/get-post

code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Axios from 'axios';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    loading: false,
    data: [],
    error: false,
  });
  const getPosts = async () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      loading: true,
      data: [],
      error: false,
    });
    // try {
    //   const response = await Axios.post('/users/post', {
    //     //datas
    //   });
    //   setState({
    //     ...state,
    //     loading: false,
    //     data: response.data,
    //   });
    // } catch (err) {
    //   setState({
    //     error: true,
    //   });
    // }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getPosts()
  }, [])
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {state.loading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator />
      ) : (
        state.data.map(({ title }, key) => {
          <Text {...{ key }}>{title}</Text>;
        })
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```